# Can I get away by not using Datastore and use only Search for persistence?

Tags: google-app-engine

Here, https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/, the documentation says,

**Documents and indexes are saved in a separate persistent store optimized for search operations**

So does that mean, and if my application permits, I can store all my documents only in 'search' and I can get away using the NDB datastore completely?

Comment: you should carefully calculate the costs for each option however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes you can do this , Search API is independent of datastore. but for large data set datastore is recommended as the search API will return maximum 10,000 results and you can store maximum of 250 GB data in them.